# How to check Xcode 6.4 code after switching to Xcode 7

Tags: xcode

I have saved a version of my app code that runs on XCode 6.4 and made a copy and converted it to work with the latest XCode 7 beta.

The problem is Xcode_6.4.dmg was auto-installed using the App Store and I don't have that file available and I can't download it because it is installed from the App Store.  I have some the beta versions but not the released.

Will I be able to run my Swift 1.2 code somehow as a baseline to whether a bug existed before the transition to Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Xcode 6.4 at http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg

You can manually keep any number of Xcode versions in /Applications. Just name each one uniquely before opening them.

Comment: Thanks EricS, that will work.  I also just figured that out for myself and am currently doing the download.

Comment: Start at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and select only Developer Tools. Looks like it is still there.